# How to add a delay before I can press space bar to reshoot the bullet so i dont get the occasional glitch were the bullet dont go anywere

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how to code in python and this is space invader which I'm creating by myself. it works fine except for when I press the spacebar too early, the bullet appears and doesn't move.

I've tried giving the bullet a state (see in code) that did not work, that is the best I can do, I thought about adding a delay but I don't know how to do that.

```
import turtle
import os

bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.color("blue")
bullet.shape("circle")
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed(0)
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.shapesize(0.5,0.5)
bullet.hideturtle()

bulletspeed = 25

bulletstate = "ready"

def fire_bullet():
    global bulletstate
    if bulletstate == "ready":
        bulletstate = "fire"
        x = player.xcor()
        y = player.ycor() +15
        bullet.setpos(x, y)
        bullet.showturtle()
turtle.listen():
     turtle.onkeypress(fire_bullet, 'space')

while True:
     if bulletstate == "fire":
        y = bullet.ycor()
        y += bulletspeed
        bullet.sety(y)

    #border bullet check
    if bullet.ycor() > 275:
        bullet.hideturtle()
        bulletstate = "ready"
```

Comment: Could you be please more clear in what and where is the delay applied? I made an asnwer but it might seem I missunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add delay to any function by using module `time` and `time.sleep(5)` where 5 is the number of seconds for the delay. I don't understand where do you specifically want your delay, but you can add `time.sleep()` anywhere to delay an specific action. If you are creating a game where there's `bulletspeed` and a variation in `y` (distance) you can use `time.sleep(y/bulletspeed)` (given the premise they are both expressed in the same value) to delay your action by the time it will take the bullet (given a certain speed) to cover that distance (variation in y)

```
import turtle
import os
import time

bullet = turtle.Turtle()
bullet.color("blue")
bullet.shape("circle")
bullet.penup()
bullet.speed(0)
bullet.setheading(90)
bullet.shapesize(0.5,0.5)
bullet.hideturtle()

bulletspeed = 25

bulletstate = "ready"

def fire_bullet():
    global bulletstate
    if bulletstate == "ready":
        bulletstate = "fire"
        x = player.xcor()
        y = player.ycor() +15
        bullet.setpos(x, y)
        bullet.showturtle()
turtle.listen():
     turtle.onkeypress(fire_bullet, 'space')

while True:
     if bulletstate == "fire":
        y = bullet.ycor()
        y += bulletspeed
        time.sleep(2) #This means it'll take 2 seconds since y has defined to apply the next function. You can also try a combination of time and speed so you can measure distance for instance: time.sleep(bulletspeed/y). 
        bullet.sety(y)

    #border bullet check
    if bullet.ycor() > 275:
        bullet.hideturtle()
        bulletstate = "ready"
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to freeze the game for 2 seconds. I think he wants to forbid fire for 2 (or whatever) seconds

Comment: I'll ask for clarification in the comments, if my answer is off I'll delete it, thanks for your comment